# Is there a way to set which projects get built based on an environment variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with 15+ projects. I want to exclude some of these projects from being compiled when an environment variable is set.

I know you can do this via a build configuration, but we'd like to avoid having to maintain several build configurations.

Ideally, if environment variable "BUILDCORE" is set, I would only build 7 of the 15 projects.

Comment: Not really, just like there is no way to this with registry keys, or named pipes. You will need to think outside the box here a little, and possibly use scripts with msbuild

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set which projects get built based on an environment variable?

AFAIK, there is no directly way to do this in Visual Studio. But you can try to following workaround, check if it works for you.

Add a blank project to the solution use `Condition=" '$(ENVBuildSetValue)' == 'BUILDCORE' "`, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</project>`, place below scripts:

```
<Target Name="BuildCore" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(ENVBuildSetValue)' == 'BUILDCORE' ">
    <Message Text="Build projects for build core!"></Message>
    <MSBuild Projects="..\theother\theother.csproj" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=xxxx;Platform=xxxx" />

    <MSBuild Projects="..\Another\Another.csproj" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=xxxx;Platform=xxxx" />
</Target>
```

Then build this project when environment variable "BUILDCORE" is set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Then build this project when environment variable "BUILCORE" is set" - doesn't that just bring me to back to the original problem - how do I tell msbuild to only build this project if environment variable is set?

Comment: @sgonzalez, there is a `Condition=" '$(ENVBuildSetValue)' == 'BUILDCORE' "`, only when you environment variable is set to BUILDCORE, this target will be executed, the projects will be built.